# Dateadd function to convert epoch time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, h2, database-administration

I am having preexisting table name 'ABC' in H2 Database.and description is,

```
FIELD              | TYPE                           | NULL | KEY | DEFAULT
ID                 | DECIMAL(19)                    | NO   |     | NULL
EVENT              | BIGINT                         | YES  |     | NULL
```

in 'EVENT' column I have some unix timestamps (epoch time in millisec.) data.

```
ID |   EVENT
1  |  1468318907575 
2  |  1468321000459
```

using DATEADD function we can convert unix timestamp into normal date.
but the input needed is in seconds (11 Digits).

Is there any way i can write a sql function which takes data from my EVENT column and convert it into DATE format same like below function is doing for values in ABC table (13 digits) bigint value.

```
select DATEADD('SECOND', 1348560343, DATE '1970-01-01');
```

please help me in this.

Thanks in advance !!!

Reagrds

Comment: I don't see a PL/SQL question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select DATEADD('SECOND', SUBSTRING(Event,1,11), DATE '1970-01-01');

Comment: i want to divide the event value by 1000 actually, can we do that.

Comment: select DATEADD('SECOND', (event_time)/1000, DATE '1970-01-01') workinng now

Comment: Yes you surely can but result would be same.           select DATEADD('SECOND', Event/1000, DATE '1970-01-01');

Comment: Mark it as answer if you found it usefull. Happy coding